# Does a power ring (Green Lantern's ring) automatically transport a new wielder to Oa?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, green-lantern

Have there been canon times when the ring simply goes to the new wielder and brings them the power battery, but does not transport them to Oa once charged?

Comment: Almost every time in the comics is like that, AFAIK. No transport to OA.

Comment: @Renan That's true. When I finally read reprints of the earliest Hal Jordan stories from the Silver Age, I was startled to see that for a long time (over a year, anyway) the stories showed that he was acting as "Green Lantern" on Earth *without* having ever heard of the planet Oa, nor of some little blue guys called "The Guardians of the Universe." They knew about him, but he didn't know about them. (For a while.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the extended universe, and not just comics, just as an example, the DC Animated film *First Flight*. Hal Jordan gets the ring and is exploring his new powers and abilities around Earth when Sinestro, Kilowog, and some other Lanterns show up to take him to Oa to explain what's going on and what being a Green Lantern means.

Comment: OP mentioned "canon times", which _First Flight_ is not a part of. As per the "extended universe", the tag relates to the DCEU movies, which FF is also not a part of... So this isn't really an answer of its own. Come to think of it, the DCEU isn't canon either, so the tag should probably go as well!